# LinearLayout with selector and custom view on top

Tags: android

I have a LinearLayout with a custom view on top of it. The veiw is 1px smaler than the layout.
I want the layout to change it's background color when view is pressed or gains focuse.

I have implemented the selector with the drawables for the layout and it's all wroking when i click on the layout. But because there is only 1 px clickable space I want my custom view that is on top of it to change the relevant properties for the layout uderneath.

Is there any way I can do that? Can the custom view dispatch evnets to the parrent Layout if the layout is not customised ?.

I can easly change the background color programatically for the Layout that the view is on when clicked by just accessing it's parent, but I want the backgroud color to chagnge for shor time and go back to it's default color. Like with the ListView items.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the handler in the ui thread, as a global at the top.

Handler handler = new Handler();

Then use to change your layout colors back:

```
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run() 
        {

        }
    }, 1000);
```

Comment: Hi Noah thanks for code it look very neat. I think ill use that option. Thank you both.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to change the background color or image only for a short time on clicking your custom view. If that's the problem you can call the following method in the onClick() of the custom view

```
public void changeBg(){
  LinearLayout layout=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.your_Layout_id);
  Drawable temp=layout.getBackground();
  layout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.your_drawable);
  try{
       Thread.sleep(2000);
  }catch(Exception ex){}
  layout.setBackgroundDrawable(temp);
}
```

I think this is what you were searching for.

Comment: Hi thanks for reply. I am aware of that option but I think using. Thread.sleep isnt the best option to use in main UI thread. Sorry i didn't mentione that this is all in my main UI thread.

Comment: I might use Thread and handler and pass the Layout to a handler and change the background there for one sec. But I.thought I can.do.that wythout using Threads or handlers.

Comment: I don't think there are any other ways to do it without using Thread or handler.